# Using an Update Panel to Rotate through different .ascx files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the update panel and timer in the past to create a slideshow using ASP.net.  I would like to do the same thing, except instead or rotating through images, I'd like to rotate though .ascx file.  Is this possible?  This is what I have so far, but I am stuck on how to access the .ascx from the code behind file.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="SlideShow" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <img runat="server" id="SlideShowImage1" src="~/Controls/Testimonials.ascx" alt="Testimonial" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="SlideShowText" Text="First Slide" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SlideShowTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="SlideShowTimer" runat="server" Interval="15000" OnTick="SlideShowTimer_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void SlideShowTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime later = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(.5);
        while (DateTime.Now < later)
        {

        }

        this.SlideShowImage1.Src = RandomImageName();
        this.SlideShowText.Text = this.SlideShowImage1.Src.ToString();

    }
    private string RandomImageName()
    {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int RandomInt = rand.Next(0, 5);

        switch (RandomInt)
        {

            case 0:
                return "~/Controls/Testimonials.ascx";
                break;
            case 1:
                return "~/Controls/Testimonials2.ascx";
                break;
            case 2:
                return "~/Controls/Testimonials3.ascx";
                break;
            default:
                return "~/Controls/Testimonials4.ascx";
                break;

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would imagine you'd have to have code behind for each .ascx file, and do your processing there.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add below directive in aspx file on top

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ucLoanTerms" Src="ucLoanTerms.ascx" %>
```

(2) Then Add following in your form where you want to dynamically load user controls

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

(3) Following code in your code behind file Page_Load method,

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
ucLoanTerms lt = (ucLoanTerms) LoadControl("ucLoanInfo.ascx");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lt);
```

I also found this good article on dynamically loading user controls.

http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/11/Loading-UserControl-Dynamically-in-UpdatePanel.aspx